# Appending default value (0) of char type to string

Tags: java, string, char

```
public class Test {
    static char ch;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = Character.toString(ch);
        System.out.println("abc" + str + "def");
    }
}
```

Console output : `abc`

Expected output : `abc def`

Since default char value is 0(space). Any concept I'm missing here?

Comment: actually char ch = 0, means NUL. I mis-understood it with a space. Thanks! https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to standard -static variables are by default initialized to zero (0 and not '0')or blank. But it's a good practice to always initialize it explicitly.

```
static char ch = 0; //=>abcdef or static char ch = ' '; =>abc def
```

or if you want value to 0 use-

```
static char ch = '\0'; //=>abcdef
```

Comment: `'0'` is not the same as `(char) 0`

Comment: I'm not getting expected output. Anything on it would be appreciating. thanks!

Comment: char c = '\0'; use this if you want char value as 0

Comment: Even though, not getting expected output.

Comment: use this--static char ch = 0; String str = String.valueOf(ch);
         System.out.println("abc" + str + "def");